# How do you show tab when clicking a button?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG tabs and after doing a lot of research on this I can't find a good solution. I'm trying to show **Tab 2** when a button is clicked. Basically, I want **to hide Tab 2 by defaul**t and when clicking on a button show it. Does anyone know how to make this happen? Thanks a lot in advanced!

Here's my code:  [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O61sni8DvbTplO5qu1YZ?p=preview)

```
<p-tabView (onChange)="onChange($event)" [activeIndex]="selectedIndex">
 <p-tabPanel header="first" [selected]="true">
  <first></first>

</p-tabPanel>
 <p-tabPanel header="second">
      <ng-template pTemplate="content">
          <second></second>
      </ng-template>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to show or display a tab ? You just have to add a condition to this tab in order to show it or not by adding the `*ngIf` directive on the `p-tabPanel` you want to manage :

```
<p-tabPanel header="second" *ngIf="showTab2">
    Content of tab 2
</p-tabPanel>
```

Then you just have to initialize `showTab2` boolean to false in order to hide the tab at the beginning. Finally, set it to true when you click on the button to display it.

```
showTab2 = false;

showSecondTab() {
    this.showTab2 = true;
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Su6hGKwfWkj0k0aMA5r6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help someone. On the latest primeng version V6 and above You can find the property called `Active Index`. Using this you can easily trigger button click event.

```
<p-tabView [activeIndex]="index">
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
        Content 1
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

In your ts file :

```
index: number = 0; 

 showSecondTab() {
    this.index = (this.index === 0) ? this.index =1 : this.index ;
  }
```

Hope it helps